# Create Transparent iOS App

Tags: ios, transparent

i would like to know, if it's possible meanwhile to create an transparent app for iOS which is on top of all other apps and transparent?
I found a topic, which is already 4 years old, so maybe meanwhile it's possible to do so?

Something like Picture in Picture, but for the whole app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m372t.jpg)

Comment: No, this is not possible. You can't access home screen context from an application.

Answer (score 0):

So far i know it's not possible. You can create widgets though in notification center.

Comment: Can you maybe support me a working App Extension, that shows an image?

Comment: This won't do what you're asking for. Your basic design (display something over other apps) is not permitted, even if you found a tricky way to implement it. It would be too easy to abuse.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do (would need more details), an extension could provide the functionality you're looking for but with a different way to access that functionality.

[image]

Action extensions are a way to integrate with other apps, think tapping that Safari button at the bottom and having the option to add as fav or add to home screen.

Share extensions are a way to share with other apps that support the type of data you want to share, think sharing a photo from the Photos app by sending the photo directly to Messages through the share button.

Today extensions appear when you pull down from the status bar on your phone, think calendar, stocks, and many other apps have them too.

You can read about the other extension [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/).

Comment: I already tried this approach, but i cant get the view controller which is opened with the extension transparent :(

Comment: Well you won't ever be able to see the springboard from an app (the springboard is the grid of app icons when you unlock your phone) but you can have a view controller that is on top of another without having it full screen.

Comment: Hello bensarz, what exactly do you mean by "but you can have a view controller that is on top of another" do you mean another view controller, or what i need: another app?

Comment: Forget about other apps. In the iOS world, you're stuck in your own app, that's it. What I mean is that you can present a view controller on top of another using a model segue. That segue can be configured to display on top of the current context; aka if you have transparency in the top view controller, you'll be able to see the view controller that's underneath. Check this link for more info: https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/difference-of-overfullscreen-and-overcurrentcontext-modalpresentationstyle-in-ios/

Comment: Thanks @bensarz, this i know already. Maybe i can manipulate the PiP function of the AVMediaPlayer. Thanks for your answer.